# File modification detected error while training a ml model in ML.NET package in a console app in visual studio 2022

Tags: console-application, visual-studio-2022, training-data, filenotfounderror, ml.net-model-builder

I created a value prediction ML.NET package model in console app in VS 2022 and got the desired output but due to framework issue. I had to migrate to 4.8 framework and since in normal console app the framework choosing option in not there. I moved to console app(.net framework) in VS 2022.But now after training the model it shows a warning as file modification detected. What should i do to make the training and consumption file to be generated without any issue.[Error image uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7MCW.png)

I created a value prediction ML.NET package model in console app in VS 2022 and got the desired output. But I want to migrate to 4.8 framework.so far i used this console app[previously used console app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbv0T.png)and because of there is no framework choosing option in this. I moved to console app[migrated console app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Y86.png) in VS 2022. But now in the process of creating a ML.NET model,after training the model, the required consumption and training.cs is not generated and it shows a warning as file modification detected.[Error image uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7MCW.png). What should i do to make the training and consumption file to be generated without any issue in the desired console app in 4.8 .NET framework?